# SQL Counting and ordering by duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I found another thread with this similar question but the query wasn't working for me for some  reason or another.

I have a table like so:

> id | 1 1 5 3 5

I need to use just SQL to echo out the most duplicated number

For instance, that would output:

> id | 1 5 3 5

If that makes sense.

How would I achieve this?

Thank you so much

Comment: Your example makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RETURNING JUST UNIQUE ID's**

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM myTable

ID   |
---------------
1    |
5    |
3    |
```

See [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b34f/1)

**RETURNING JUST THE MOST DUPLICATED ID WITH COUNT**

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS Duplicates FROM test
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY Duplicates DESC
LIMIT 1;

ID   |  Duplicates
---------------
1    |  2

// without the LIMIT clause

ID   |  Duplicates
---------------
1    |  2
5    |  2
3    |  1
```

See [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b34f/2)

Or, as you see above, there may be TWO ID's that have been duplicated the same amount of times. You could do this, which would return both the highest duplicated ID's, if they're equal:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS Duplicates
FROM test
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) = (
  SELECT COUNT(id) AS great
  FROM test
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY great DESC
  LIMIT 1
)

ID   |  Duplicates
---------------
1    |  2
5    |  2
```

See [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960a0/4)

**RETURNING JUST UNIQUE ID's IN PURE PHP**

```
$results = // query
$results = array_unique($results);
```

Comment: I haven't used any count methods as your example output didn't show any kind of count. I'm purely returning unique ID's, as I believe that is what your goal actually is. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that if you select more columns such as `select distinct id,c2,c3` this will select the distinct **row**, not the distinct values of id. Beware :-)

Comment: @Bell, you're totally correct. His example only used one column, so my answer was given for just that. I actually think your answer is the better one, as the OP's explanation described just what you provided, but his example output was totally different. Confused :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by together with a count, like this:

```
select * from t group by id order by count(id) desc
```

And add a limit clause in order to get the single most duplicated value:

```
select * from t group by id order by count(id) desc limit 1
```